# How can I deter rats from entering my home's structure?

Tags: pest-control, pest, rodent

We have what others have referred to as roof rats that come and go into the subfloor space between our 1st and 2nd floors. Very little to no recent evidence of them in the attic, and quite literally no evidence within the house whatsoever.

Steps we’ve taken over the last 2.5 years:

- I have had probably 10 different pest companies come to assess the house and do seal work. We have spent nearly $5k sealing up whatever these guys turn up.
- I manage about 10 bait stations around the property, after about a one year contract from another company that was doing it for me.
- I had a handy man create a hatch access door to the subfloor and I have personally snap trapped dozens of rats there.
- I have had probably 3 different plumbers and 3 different HVAC companies come out to give their assessment, to no avail.
- I’ve tried those stupid noise machines and predator sound boxes, light boxes
- I’ve sprayed powerful peppermint all around the perimeter of our house
- I’ve moved game cameras around the property, leaving them for many nights at a time. Only ever saw birds and squirrels.

Nobody can seem to figure out how they are getting in, and poison+trapping isn’t cutting it. The smell is awful, they are chewing our house from the inside. And to top it all off, we have a newborn in the house now and I am terrified of all the sick and disease these rodents can carry.

I don’t know if I’m pleading for help or what I’m doing on here, I’m just at my wits end and I’ll try absolutely anything you guys suggest.

Comment: We lived in the countryside and had rats in the attic every time the crops were harvested. Solution was to throw the cat in to the attic - absolute carnage and then total silence... need a farm cat.

Comment: Youtube's "Twin Home Experts" have videos about rats getting in through the sewer or vent pipes, and using smoke machines to find the broken pipes where the rats are able to get in.

Comment: twins with the smoke machine:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ko3hJiDI9yk

Comment: did you use thermal game cameras?

Comment: i find pest companies don't do a good job of finding the entry points and you pretty much have to inspect yourself.

Comment: thermal cameras can also be used to look for intrusion points.  Heat the house up much higher than ambient and go around your house at night and see if you can spot any areas where heat is escaping.

Comment: if those measures still don't work I'd consider pepper spray into the joist bays - though I'd first test a small portion in a place I could clean and see how it ages and if having it in an inaccessible place like a joist bay would lead to different problems.  drill little holes into the rim joist like they do for blown insulation.

Comment: sometimes rodents access through cable entry points eg by using utility conduits. Do you know where your electrical etc... enters the house?