# How to get rid of rats in subfloor

Tags: pest-control, pest, rodent

We have what others have referred to as roof rats that come and go into the subfloor space between our 1st and 2nd floors. Very little to no recent evidence of them in the attic, and quite literally no evidence within the house whatsoever. We aren't on a septic system. Just a 2-story single family residential home.

Steps we’ve taken over the last 2.5 years:

-I have 2 cats and a dog.
-I have had probably 10 different pest companies come to assess the house and do seal work. We have spent nearly $5k sealing up whatever these guys turn up.
-I manage about 10 bait stations around the property, after about a one year contract from another company that was doing it for me.
-I had a handy man create a hatch access door to the subfloor and I have personally snap trapped dozens of rats there.
-I have had probably 3 different plumbers and 3 different HVAC companies come out to give their assessment, to no avail.
-I’ve tried those stupid noise machines and predator sound boxes, light boxes
-I’ve sprayed powerful peppermint all around the perimeter of our house
-I’ve moved game cameras around the property, leaving them for many nights at a time. Only ever saw birds and squirrels.

Nobody can seem to figure out how they are getting in, and poison+trapping isn’t cutting it. The smell is awful, they are chewing our house from the inside. And to top it all off, we have a newborn in the house now and I am terrified of all the sick and disease these rodents can carry.

I don’t know if I’m pleading for help or what I’m doing on here, I’m just at my wits end and I’ll try absolutely anything you guys suggest.

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: Dulpicate of https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/296278/how-can-i-deter-rats-from-entering-my-homes-structure apparently by same author in a different account.

Comment: Years ago had mice/rat problem.  Used the common blood thinning poisons that did not work.  Changed the poison type and all gone in a few weeks.  You need to get rid of the rat nest inside the house, if the house has been sealed up outside.

Comment: Get a cat, been suggested before.